# Will Dell P2417H, 23.8" monitor be a good choice as second monitor to iMac 27”?

Tags: monitors, multiple-monitors

I plan to buy second monitor for my iMac 27” as I understand that it will raise my productivity in design projects and also one of the reason is starting to learn front-end development. I do not want to go over 200 euros and currently feel that this Dell model could be the right choice. Maybe someone can give me feedback on it or suggest other, better choice? I also like Samsung monitor, maybe could try something else also.
[https://www.amazon.com/Dell-Professional-P2417H-LED-Lit-Monitor/dp/B01FGCJE26](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FGCJE26)

Comment: What requirements do you have for a secondary monitor? What resolution and size would you like? Is a TN panel OK, or would you like an IPS panel? IMO, you are not going to find a monitor that you will be happy with for that price. The quality compared to the iMac just wont be there.

Comment: I just bought Dell P2417H, but at the first feeling wasn’t surprised of the quality. Actually, I wanted this model because I knew that it would be ok choice as secondary screen, but the one I used earlier was U2417 model, so the UltraSharp would be better instead of the P I took. I plan to change it. I was surprised how bad my eyes felt after working for some short time, but the U model doesn’t was absolutely fine.